# (datatool in LaTeX)DTLforeach: Can't assign XXX there is no keys in XXX?

Tags: latex

i am a beginner for LaTeX, and currently trying to create tables from text files(just for some reason the data was generated from an other program and written in a .txt file)

And here is one of the text file:(just integrated it into latex)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{d11.csv}
Zeit/s AMES\_13 AMES\_14 AMES\_15 AMES\_16
3,0 000  8,760V 0,000  0,216mA
6,0 000  13,120V 0,000  0,169mA
9,0 000  16,550V 0,000  0,132mA
12,0 000  19,660V 0,000  0,103mA
15,0 000  21,730V 0,000  0,081mA
18,0 000  23,580V 0,000  0,066mA
\end{filecontents*}
```

And i tried to use  package's DTLforeach to generate a latex Table form it using:

```
\DTLsetseparator{ }
\DTLloaddb[
           keys={zeit,am1,am2,am3,am4}
]{d11db}{d11.csv}

 .... Some other texts...

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\bfseries Zeit/s &
\bfseries AMES\_13 &
\bfseries AMES\_14 &
\bfseries AMES\_15 &
\bfseries AMES\_16 \\\hline
\DTLforeach{d11db}{\zeit=zeit,\am1=am1,\am2=am2,\am3=am3,\am4=am4
}{%
  \zeit & \am1 & \am2 & \am3 & \am4 \\\hline
}
\end{tabular}
```

And then when i trying to compile it, LaTeX(or pdflatex) just showing me the Error:

```
Package datatool Error: Can't assign \am4 : there is no key `am4 ' in data base `d11db'.
```

If i delete \am4=am4, it shows then am3 is not exsits... Can someone tell me how to solve this error? Thx (and sry for my poor english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keys` option specifies the actual header names you used in your CSV. Here's an extract from the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) [user's guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) (section **5.2 Loading a Database from an External ASCII File**):

> **`keys`**
>
> This is a comma-separated list of keys to use, where the keys are
>   listed in the same order as the columns. If the file has a header,
>   these keys will override the values given in the header row. If the
>   file has no header row and no keys are supplied in `<options>`, then
>   the keys will be given by `\dtldefaultkey<n>`, where `<n>` is the
>   `\dtldefaultkey` column number and `\dtldefaultkey` defaults to “Column”.
>   Note that the list of keys must be delimited by braces since they
>   contain commas.

So, my suggestion would be to rather use:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{d11.csv}
zeit,am1,am2,am3,am4
3,0 000  8,760V 0,000  0,216mA
...
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[
  keys={zeit,am1,am2,am3,am4},
  headers={Zeit/s,AMES\_13,AMES\_14,AMES\_15,AMES\_16}
]{d11db}{d11.csv}
```

Note the use of the `headers` key:

> **`headers`**
>
> This is a comma-separated list of headers. If not supplied, the
>   header will be the same as that given in the header row, or the key
>   if there is no header row. Note that the list of headers must be
>   delimited by braces since they contain commas.